# Smoothing a sharp disappearing for transient div

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I have created a box to toggle between appearing and disappearing via a toggle button.

The problems are:

- The first time, the appearing height is sharp and not smooth.
- The disappearing height is happening sharp and at the end instead of smooth.

I am not a web expert. All I have written are what I have got from different places and assembled. Please feel free to fix any other CSS/JS mistakes too. But the above issues are what I am mainly looking for.

```js
function toggle_elem()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById('elemid');
    if(elem.style.display == 'none')
    {
        elem.style.display = 'block';
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            elem.style.opacity = 1;
            elem.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            elem.style.height = '100px';
        },0);
    }
    else
    {
        elem.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            elem.style.display = 'none';
            elem.style.height = '0';
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

```css
#elemid {
    border: 1px solid black;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: height 0.3s, width 0.3s, padding 0.3s, visibility 0.3s, 0.3s ease opacity, opacity 0.3s ease-out, 0.3s ease transform;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button onclick="toggle_elem()">Toggle</button>
</div>

<div id="elemid" style="display:none">aaaaa</div>

<div>
<button >Next button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there for the smooth transition in disappearing animation.
The only thing you need to modify is this

```
elem.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
//this is to support the css animation
elem.style.height = '0'; //move your height set outside of `setTimeout`
window.setTimeout(function(){
   //only set `display` none after the animation completed
   elem.style.display = 'none';
}, 300);
```

Full code

```js
function toggle_elem() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('elemid');
  if (elem.style.display == 'none') {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      elem.style.opacity = 1;
      elem.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
      elem.style.height = '100px';
    }, 0);
  } else {
    elem.style.transform = 'scale(0)';

    elem.style.height = '0';
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      elem.style.display = 'none';
    }, 300);
  }
}
```

```css
#elemid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: height 0.3s, width 0.3s, padding 0.3s, visibility 0.3s, 0.3s ease opacity, opacity 0.3s ease-out, 0.3s ease transform;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="toggle_elem()">Toggle</button>
</div>

<div id="elemid" style="display:none">aaaaa</div>

<div>
  <button>Next button</button>
</div>
```